Custom Jetty error handler not used in Spring Boot application
Have a Spring Boot application with Jetty as embedded web server and a custom Jetty error handler. The custom error handler has worked before, but after some Spring Boot / Jetty upgrade the custom error handler has stopped being used.
Using: Spring Boot 3.1.10 and Jetty 11.0.20
The error handler is set with the following:
public class AcmeApiApp implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> {
   
    ...
   
    @Override
    public void customize(JettyServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        JettyServerCustomizer customizer = server -> server.setErrorHandler(new SilentErrorHandler());
        factory.addServerCustomizers(customizer);
    }

    private static final class SilentErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
        ...
    }

    ...
}

The error handler is not used on an invalid request. Instead JettyEmbeddedErrorHandler is used.
$ curl -H "Content-Type: invalid" http://localhost:8090
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400 Bad Request</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>400</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Bad Request</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-6d66d76a</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

Have located the issue to: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.getErrorHandler()
public static ErrorHandler getErrorHandler(Server server, ContextHandler context) {
    ErrorHandler errorHandler = null;
    if (context != null) {
        errorHandler = context.getErrorHandler();
    }

    if (errorHandler == null && server != null) {
        errorHandler = (ErrorHandler)server.getBean(ErrorHandler.class);
    }

    return errorHandler;
}

The server object has the custom error handler server.getBean(ErrorHandler.class) = SilentErrorHandler but context is not null and context.getErrorHandler() is JettyEmbeddedErrorHandler.
How to configure so the custom handler is always used?
Any help appreciated!

Jetty 11 is now at End of Community Support, you should be using Jetty 12 at this point in time.
You seem to be using Spring with Servlet.
Set the ErrorPageErrorHandler on ServletContextHandler or WebAppContext, this is a feature of the Servlet spec, it has it's own error handling (and quite a bit of configuration around it too)
All you did was set the server level ErrorHandler which is used for all things not in a Servlet Context.

Thanks Joakim. The following solved it:
ErrorHandler errorHandler = new SilentErrorHandler();
    server.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    server.getHandlers().forEach((handler) -> {
        if (handler instanceof WebAppContext webAppContext) {
            webAppContext.addConfiguration(new AbstractConfiguration(new AbstractConfiguration.Builder()) {
                @Override
                public void configure(WebAppContext context) throws Exception {
                    context.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
                }
        });
    }
});

